# python multiprocessing. The subprocesses all stop before their tasks are done

Tags: python, web-crawler, python-multiprocessing

I used the python multiprocessing module to test some proxies.They worked well at the beginning.However, after a few more minutes, they became slower.Then I checked the task manager,and I found out that there were only 2 subprocesses left.Later , all processes stopped , even though their taskes were not done!

May I ask why T^T

```
#coding:utf-8
import urllib2
import re
import cookielib
import time
import urllib
import multiprocessing

h = {
                'Connection' : 'keep-alive' ,
                'Accept' : '*/*' ,
                'User_Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36' ,
                }

f_r=open('ip2.txt','r')
ips=f_r.readlines()
#print rows

#print ips

q = multiprocessing.Queue()
for ip in ips:
    q.put(ip.replace('\n' , ''))

def worker(q):
    global h
    while not q.empty():
        ip = q.get()
        proxy_ip='http://'+ip
        print proxy_ip
        proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler( { 'http' : proxy_ip } )
        cj = cookielib.CookieJar()  
        cookie_support = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj)  
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(cookie_support, urllib2.HTTPHandler)  
        opener.add_handler( proxy )
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)
        try:
            urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('http://www.zhihu.com' ,headers=h),timeout=3)
            print ip+'   OK!!!'
            with open('ip_canuse.txt','a') as f_w:
                f_w.write(ip + '\n')
            break
        except Exception,e:
            print e
            continue

if __name__ == '__main__':         
    ps=[]
    for i in range(10):
        ps.append(multiprocessing.Process(target = worker, args = (q,)))
    for p in ps:
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()
    for p in ps:
        p.join()

    print "end"
```

Comment: each one of your workers seems to empty the whole q queue by itself?

Comment: When you say - *even though their taskes were not done!* - What did you see instead? What was done?

Comment: thanks  for your replies!!!  I'm a fool. That 'break' mustn't be there!!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I added an unneccessary 'break' there, and this caused the problem.

Comment: I edited your answer, to make it clear that you found the solution yourself. If you disagree with my edit, you can roll it back. To roll it back, click on the "edited ... ago" link. That takes you to the edit history. From there, you can roll back to earlier revisions of your post.